# Add custom data-attribute to Wordpress navigation menu

Tags: wordpress

I've seen some similar questions here on stackoverflow, but mine is a bit different..

I need to be able to add custom data attribute to wordpress menu.
The problem i've got is that all the solutions i found, like the following, for example:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_attribs', 10, 3 );
function my_nav_menu_attribs( $atts, $item, $args )
{
  // The ID of the target menu item
  $menu_target = 365;

  // inspect $item
  if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
    $atts['data-reveal-id'] = 'myModal';
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

allows you to add the same attribute to all menu items.
What i need, is actually a way to add the same data attribute, but with different values on each element on the list.

this is pretty much what i need to achive:

```
<ul id="myMenu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">First section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#thirdPage">Third section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage"><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth section</a></li>
</ul>
```

because i need to use this plugin here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs

any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to do exact the same thing. Did you found a solution?

Comment: Yes. At the end I managed to solve this using javascript. I am writing an answer now and i'll post here for you to have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I managed to solve this using javascript.

This is what I did:

```
(function() {
  var arrayList, key, val;

  arrayList = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];

  for (key in arrayList) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)){break;}
    val = arrayList[key];
    console.log("key is " + key + " and val is " + val);
    $('li').each(function(index) {
      if (parseInt(index) === parseInt(key)) {
        return $(this).attr('data-anchor', val);
      }
    });
  }
window.CP.exitedLoop(1);


}).call(this);
```

- Create an array with the data you need
- Foreach loop to iterate trough the array
- Inside that loop, loop trough the menu items
- If the menu index is the same as the array index, append the array value as an attribute.

Here's a codepen example as well: http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/GmKqqE

Answer (score 1):

I guess the solution would be to extend the navigation items. I made this before to add icons to menu items.

Take a look over here - instead of a subheadline you cann name the field "anchortarget" (or anything else) and call it in your menu...
http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-custom-attributes-to-wordpress-menus/

If you need further hints, you should google for "wordpress + menu + custom field".

Hope this helps you. All the best

Comment: I tried downloading the final plugin just to check how the style of the subtitle works and how in general the plugin works, but i don't think it works. I don't have any "subtitle" at all. Are you sure this is still valid with wordpress updates? as the plugin seams to be at least 2years old

Comment: Hey Nick, if you go to Design > Menues (maybe it's an other name in your language or english, I just have an german version opened, but basicly the site where you can edit your menus) you can click on a panel in the upper right corner (in the german version it's called "Ansicht anpassen"). I guess you have not selected the new option, right? You could also add fields like link target (fe blank), css, XFN, ....

Comment: yes i know, i actually added a subtitle the proper way, it is just not displayed at all...
And that's the bit i can't figure out why..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, too bad, I am sorry. I would post the code I've written for my icons but the code ist like 400 lines with the walker and stuff. But as it seems you're using foundation, you should head over here -> https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/10/customize-tree-like-data-structures-wordpress-walker-class/

Even if you don't know about php or wordpress hooks this tutorial will absolutly explain every step needed to code it by hand. It works, I just tested it with my site by copy / pasting it.

If you scroll down, you'll see screenshots - they added an icon field (nearly like i did) how they did it and how they use it. After seeing this tut, honestly, I regret I made it all by myself. It was painfull - this tut just works like a charm....

Comment: I'm quite familiar with wordpress to be fair, i just wanted to know if there was a way to actually do that without having to write a full plugin..
i'm going to look at the link you suggested. Thanks for now, i'll let you knw

Comment: Ok, it seams very very detailed. Thanks again for your help and support.